# How to pass cucumber datatables to sendkeys in steps using typescript?

Tags: typescript, datatables, protractor, cucumber

Following is my feature :

```
Scenario: Login to the website
And Enter the username and password
|username |password |
|testerqp@outlook.com |123456 |
And I click the 'SignIn' button
Then I should see 'You have successfully logged in' message
```

I want to write step definition for the step "Enter the username and password"

```
When(/^Enter the username and password$/, async(table: TableDefinition) => {     
         await table.rows().forEach(element => {
         homePage.Username.sendKeys(element);
         homePage.Password.sendKeys(element);
         // });
      });
```

Note: Homepage is my page object and I have declared and identified the username and password fields there.
**My main concern is how to pass the elements through sendkeys.**

Comment: What is the problem? Please provide error messages or problems you run into. [If you need help: here is a guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: I need code snippet of how to transfer the datatable values in cucumber feature to the sendkeys in the stepdefinitions.

Comment: We aren´t any code writing service. Please share your attempts with their errors. If your attempt doesn´t work then please provide an error message....

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by just adding an array index to the element.

```
 When(/^Enter the username and password$/, async(table: TableDefinition) => {     
      await table.rows().forEach(element => {
      console.log(element);
      homePage.Username.sendKeys(element[0]);
      homePage.Password.sendKeys(element[1]);
       });
   });
```